# Execute testng xml using java main method in specified folder structure

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jar, testng

The execution in **testng.xml** is working fine but the same execution produces an exception **cannot find classpath of the test class** when executing with `main` method.

The `main` method in Java project follows below structure:
*src/main/java* - contains multiple packages including the class which contains main method
*src/test/java* - contains multiple packages for test classes and methods

When the class contains `main` method in **src/test/java** produces *main method not found error*

When the class contains `main` method in **src/main/java** produces *test class not found error*

```
// Create object of TestNG Class
TestNG runner=new TestNG();

// Create a list of String 
List<String> suitefiles=new ArrayList<String>();

// Add xml file which you have to execute
suitefiles.add("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Blog6March\\dummy16june\\testng.xml");

// now set xml file for execution
runner.setTestSuites(suitefiles);

// finally execute the runner using run method
runner.run();
```

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: I am getting mainmethod not found if my class with main method is present under src/test/java and if I keep my main class in src/main/java, I am getting class file of test class not found as below
Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: TestClass

Comment: Try to clean your project and execute one more time OR try to run other testng.xml and then run this xml file. If it does not execute properly, could you share the testng.xml code also

Comment: I am able execute my testng.xml file individually, also I am able to execute the main class if I keep all my test classes under src/main/java instead of maintaining test classes under src/test/java

Comment: make sure, you have added src/test/java to build path source

Comment: @Murthi Thanks I missed this, my test class files output folder is set to some other folder. Modified it and it worked